# Perform blob detection on matrix with openCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, blob

I have captured some data in a 16x8 heatmap matrix called pixels. 
I would like to do some blob recognition on this matrix data and display the result on the screen.

I was able to do this in a very convoluted way by displaying the data as an image and saving it to a RAM disk then performing blob recognition:

> - Display data as an image
> - get the current figure drawn
> - save image to RAM disk
> - detect blobs
> - display image

It' slow. Is there an easier/shorter way to detect blobs in a matrix? Or at least skipping the ramdisk save? Thank you!

The code:

```
# Display data as an image. maybe not necessary?
rez = plt.imshow(np.reshape(np.repeat(0,128),(16,8)),cmap=plt.cm.hot,interpolation='hanning')
plt.draw()
plt.pause(0.0005)

# read data
pixels = s.readData()
# update data
rez.set_data(np.reshape(pixels,(16,8)))

# get the current figure drawn
fig1 = plt.gcf()
# save to RAM disk
fig1.savefig('/home/pi/ramdisk/img.png', dpi=300) 
# Read image
im0 = cv2.imread("/home/pi/ramdisk/img.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
im1 = cv2.imread("/home/pi/ramdisk/img.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

im = cv2.threshold(im1, 158, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minArea =50
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
# Draw detected blobs
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im0, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,255,0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
#display image with blobs
....
```